# Matlab: how to draw a 2D geometry with curved edges in pdetool box

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pde

I'm using the `pde toolbox` in Matlab to solve the diffusion equation in 2D spatial domain. My geometry is irregular, i.e., the edges are curved lines. How can I draw that in the `pdetool box` ? Say one edge is represented by this equation `3x^2-x^3-x+2` for `x from 0 to 3`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than what I thought. Basicaly, I just have to define my curved edges using the four shapes available in the pdetool box.  For example, if I draw a big circle with redius R (region C1) in GUI and cover it with another circle with radius R-very small number (region C2), and then cover the unwanted regions with recetangles (say R1 and R2).  I can then define a curved edge as C1-C2-R1-R2 and export it the workspace.